# How to modify divs in grid template site?

Tags: css, grid

At my job they gave me a template to work with, I believe my boss bought it somewhere. But now client wants to modify the template, so I had to find out how template works.

So far I've found that it uses a 12-grid model. Bad part is I don't know if it is inui.css or something. I'm having trouble adjusting the grids, and don't have a clue on want to do.

I dont know if what I want to do is possible or very obvious, I'm actually a php intern and it's been kind of hard figuring out css.

This is the problem:

[original http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/4746/originalog.jpg](http://img46.imageshack.us/img46/4746/originalog.jpg)

And this is what i want to do:

[wanted http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/225/wantedqc.jpg](http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/225/wantedqc.jpg)

the code is:

```
<div class="grid-6">
   image here
</div>
<div class="grid-6">
   image here
</div>
<div class="grid-6">
   image here
</div>
<div class="grid-6">
   text here
</div>
```

Oh and trick is, client doesnt want it to be right under the top div, just a little bit higher.

[edit]:

This is the css in the template

```
.grid-6, .grid-half {
width: 47.917%;
}

.grids {
width: auto;
max-width: 1000px;
margin: 0px 0px 0px -1.7% !important;
list-style: none;
overflow: hidden;
letter-spacing: -.25em;
-webkit-columns: 1;
-moz-columns: 1;
columns: 1;
}

.grids [class*="grid-"]
{
display: inline-block;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 1.7% !important;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
vertical-align: top;
letter-spacing: 0;
padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

Comment: You might be looking for *Masonry*, which is a JavaScript library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way this is possible with pure CSS is by using the [Multiple Column Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/).

http://cssdeck.com/labs/qi1g3b4e

```
.foo {
  columns: 2;
}
```

Prefixes may be required:  http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn

Comment: so I should put everything inside a ul? hmm I think I'll read the w3 link you pointed out as I dont really understand that. Thanks for the links :)

Comment: The element itself doesn't matter.  It just needs to be applied to the parent container of your .grid-6 elements.

Comment: Oh ok, I think I get. I'll it try out!

Comment: how do i know what to put in the nth-child selector?

Comment: I only added the nth-child selector so you could see irregular elements stacked together.

Comment: oh in that case it's not working, i still get all the divs aligned like in the first picture.

Comment: You'll need to provide the CSS that's making the layout in your first picture.  It might be that there's something there that's working against you.

Comment: It seems to work as it should in all browsers that support the columns property:  http://cssdeck.com/labs/djoprgew

Comment: if you add more lines to any of the higher divs, both of the divs under them get align on the bottom.

Comment: The width and the inline-block are working against you.  Also, you have an incorrect number of columns:  http://cssdeck.com/labs/v6q30vdo